# mapply basics? - how to create a matrix from two vectors and a function

Tags: r, matrix, mapply

I am trying create a data.frame from which to create a graph.  I have a function and two vectors that I want to use as the two inputs.  This is a bit simplified, but basically all I have is:

```
relGPA <- seq(-1.5,1.5,.2)
avgGPA <- c(-2,0,2)

f <- function(relGPA, avgGPA) 1/(1+exp(sum(relGPA*pred.model$coef[1],avgGPA*pred.model$coef[2])))
```

and all I want is a data.frame with 3 columns for the avgGPA values, and 16 rows for the relGPA values with the resulting values in the cells.

I apologize for how basic this is, but I assure you I have tried to make this happen without your assistance.  I have tried following the examples on the sapply and mapply man pages, but I'm just a little too new to R to see what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot be tested with the information offered,  but this should work:

```
expGPA  <- outer(relGPA, avgGPA, FUN=f) # See below for way to make this "work"
```

Another useful function when you want to generate combinations is `expand.grid` and this would get you the "long form":

```
expGPA2 <-expand.grid(relGPA, avgGPA)
expGPA2$fn <- apply(expGPA2, 1, f)
```

The long form is what lattice and ggplot will expect as input format for higher level plotting.

EDIT: It may be necessary to construct a more specific method for passing column references to the function as pointed out by djhurio  and (solved) by  Sam Swift with the `Vectorize` strategy. In the case of `apply`, the `sum` function would work out of the box as described above, but the division operator would not, so here is a further example that can be generalized to more complex functions with multiple arguments. All the programmer needs is the number of the column for the appropriate argument in the "apply()"-ed" function, because (unfortunately) the column names are not carried through to the `x` argument:

```
> expGPA2$fn <- apply(expGPA2, 1, function(x) x[1]/x[2])
> str(expGPA2)
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Var1: num  -1.5 -1.3 -1.1 -0.9 -0.7 ...
 $ Var2: num  -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 ...
 $ fn  : num  0.75 0.65 0.55 0.45 0.35 ...
 - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
  ..$ dim     : int  16 3
  ..$ dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ Var1: chr  "Var1=-1.5" "Var1=-1.3" "Var1=-1.1" "Var1=-0.9" ...
  .. ..$ Var2: chr  "Var2=-2" "Var2= 0" "Var2= 2"
```

Edit2: (2013-01-05) Looking at this a year later, I realized that SamSwift's function could be vectorized by making its body use "+" instead of `sum`:

```
 1/(1+exp( relGPA*pred.model$coef[1] + avgGPA*pred.model$coef[2]) # all vectorized fns
```

Comment: `f` must be a vectorized function to use it in `outer`. And `apply` does not work like that. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks DWin, that did the trick, and djhurio you're right on as well.  I added "vf <- Vectorize(f, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)" after I defined my function, and then outer was exactly what I needed.