# How do I matricise a column/vector (applying a function like sum/diff/boolean)?

Tags: r

I have a vector, say

```
1
0
1
1
1
0
```

denoting gender.
I want to matricise this vector into an square matrix and for every pair perform a function. So say I want to sum.

```
2 1 2 2 2 1
1 0 1 1 1 0
2 1 2 2 2 1
2 1 2 2 2 1
2 1 2 2 2 1
1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Or if the rule is ‘similar is a 1’

```
1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
```

How can I create such a square matrix from a vector/column `c(1,0,1,1,1,0)`?

I have been manipulating numerous vectors but I keep on getting errors.

Comment: I suspect you want `?outer`, as in `outer(x,x,FUN=\`+\`)` but i'm not sure I follow your second example output. What does ‘*similar is a 1*’ mean?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. It would be boolean for example so if we compare row 1 with column 3 both are 1 so it becomes 1 as they are similar. However row 1 compared to column 2 becomes a 0 because 1 is dissimilar to 0.

Comment: Sounds like `outer` is definitely what you want then- `outer(x,x,FUN=\`==\`) + 0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438632/mapply-basics-how-to-create-a-matrix-from-two-vectors-and-a-function or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935146/apply-function-over-two-vectors-of-different-lengths-and-return-a-matrix-in-r

Comment: `outer(x,x,'+');outer(x,x,'==')` etc. You are looking for outer